# How to find old directories in local directory using find in AIX?

Tags: find, ksh

I need to find all old directories in current directory.
find in AIX does not provide -maxdepth parameter.
There is only -depth and -prune parameters.
It is possible to write something like following:

```
find ./* -type d -mtime +31 -prune
```

But it will not work if current directory is empty.
What is the correct way to find all old directories *in current directory only*, **not in all sub-directories of the current directory**?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Starting your find at '.' (not './*') should be enough.

Comment: "." will not work if to use -prune parameter. I need to find old directories in current directory only, not in all subdirectories of current directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I believe you likely want is something more like:

```
find . -not -name . -type d -prune -mtime +31
```

This will list the immediate directories in current directory older than 31 days.  Adding the `-not -name .` means that the current directory (root of the tree) will   already be 'false' before it gets to the `-prune` action; all the other directories will be pruned.

Comment: I did not know about -not argument. I am not sure that this will work in AIX, but I checked it now in online Linux emulator and it works as I need. Thank you.

Comment: `-not` is not standard, use `!` instead which is.

Comment: find . ! -name . -prune ...
which says to “prune” (don't descend into) any directories except “.”. http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm

Comment: But why following command does not work? find /tmp/dir ! -name /tmp/dir -type d -prune

Comment: The `-name` takes a single pathname component and should not have a '/' in the argument, hence it would match nothing.  You would have to use either `-path` or be a little smarter about which 'dir' to select.